# Auto layout vertical constraint sometimes has no effect within UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITableView. Each row contains a UIView that contains two UILabels. The vertical spacing between the two UIlabels is specified with an auto layout constraint. It looks like this:

```
+-------------------+
| +----------+      |
| | +------+ |      |
| | | text | |      |
| | +------+ |      |
| |          | ROW  |
| | +------+ |      |
| | | text | |      |
| | +------+ |      |
| +----------+      |
+-------------------+
```

This usually works but sometimes the cell is rendered without space between the UILabels. When it doesn't work no error is printed. It seems non deterministic. I.e. if I create two cells with the exact same contents one might be rendered with the correct vertical spacing and the other without the spacing.

If you have any advice on how to figure out the problem please let me know.

Right now the table uses estimated row heights which seems a little flaky.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem occasionally.
When the result of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is near to the value of `estimatedRowHeight`,ten to one this problem will appear.
So I set the value of `estimatedRowHeight` to an impossible low value,such as 2,to work around,and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.